# .NET MAUI - iOS: How to get certificate info at runtime?

Tags: ios, certificate, maui

I have a MAUI application, after build ipa file and sign it with a certificate, i want to get information of the certificate at runtime (such as the certificate in byte array format), please tell me how can i do that? Many thanks

I found this code using Security framework to get certificate, but 2 classes SecStaticCode and SecCodeSigner are not found.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Security;

public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Get the main application bundle
        NSBundle mainBundle = NSBundle.MainBundle;

        // Get the IPA path
        string ipaPath = mainBundle.BundlePath;

        // Get the digital signature data for the IPA file
        NSData signatureData = NSData.FromFile(ipaPath + "/_CodeSignature/CodeResources");

        // Create an instance of the Security framework's SecStaticCode class
        var staticCode = new SecStaticCode(ipaPath);

        // Get the signing information
        SecCodeSigner signer = staticCode.SigningInformation;

        // Get the list of certificates used to sign the IPA
        SecCertificate[] certificates = signer.SigningCertificates;

        if (certificates != null && certificates.Length > 0)
        {
            //Get the first certificate(you can iterate through all if there are multiple)
            SecCertificate certificate = certificates.First();

            //Get the certificate data
            NSData certificateData = certificate.GetEncoded();

            //You can now use the certificate information as needed
            Console.WriteLine("IPA Certificate: " + certificateData.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [Security](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security), the [SecStaticCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secstaticcode) is included in the security framework, however, `SecCodeSigner ` is not in it. So this could a potential issue on Apple side.